# How do i swipe up a view using accessibility in android?

Tags: java, android, mobile, accessibility, uber-api

I am using gesture class to swipe up but it does not work in android
there are no logs even

```
GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
```

and moving using

```
path.moveTo(rightSizeOfScreen, middleYValue);
path.lineTo(leftSideOfScreen, middleYValue);
```

Comment: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/STnJC.jpg">

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: see the screenshot attached. i want to swipe up the list

Answer (score 0):

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo products = getRootInActiveWindow().findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("id").get(0);
        //product list shown

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int middleYValue = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2;
        final int leftSideOfScreen = displayMetrics.widthPixels / 4;
        final int rightSizeOfScreen = leftSideOfScreen * 3;
        GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
        Path path = new Path();


            path.moveTo(rightSizeOfScreen, middleYValue);
            path.lineTo(leftSideOfScreen, middleYValue);

        gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 100, 50));
        gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 100, 50));
```